# Logging in Custom Handler for TorchServe

Tags: python, pytorch, torchserve

I have written a custom handler for an DL model using torch-serve and am trying to understand how to add manual log messages to the handler. I know that I can simply `print` any messages and it will show them within the `MODEL_LOG` logger at level INFO.

What if I want to add a custom message at DEBUG level or ERROR level? When I try to initialise a logger using
`logger = logging.getLogger('model_log')` and add a message within the handler using `logger.error` I see the output on screen but at INFO level.

What is the best way to create log messages within a handler at a chosen log-level?

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to do something similar. I found example logger usage in [`base_handler.py`](https://github.com/pytorch/serve/blob/master/ts/torch_handler/base_handler.py), where the logger is initialized on line 23 as:
`logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` and used in several places in the rest of the source file, typically as: `logger.debug()` or `logger.warning()`, etc. I am assuming that these messages end up in the relevant files under the `logs/` folder of TorchServe. I hope it is useful for your particular use case.